# debug they have same value but still get index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

When I debug my code, the value of the variables shows that they are equal to my limit condition but my while loop still works

I'm trying to stop my while loop by this limitation:

```
while (i + j) != len(fruits):
```

Even though (i+j) is equal to len(fruits), the loop still works, it doesn't break.
It should be broken when it meets my limitation.
My code is below:

```
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def totalFruit(self, fruits: List[int]) -> int:
        pointed = [0 for i in range(max(fruits) + 1)]
        maX, count = 0, 0
        count_type = 0
        i, j = 0, 0
        while (i + j) != len(fruits):
            while count_type < 3:
                if pointed[fruits[i + j]] == 0:
                    count_type += 1
                    if count_type < 3:
                        count += 1
                        pointed[fruits[i + j]] += 1
                        j += 1

                elif count_type < 3 and pointed[fruits[i + j]] != 0:
                    pointed[fruits[i + j]] += 1
                    count += 1
                    j += 1
                
                if count > maX: maX = count

            if pointed[fruits[i]] == 1: count_type -= 2

            pointed[fruits[i]] -= 1
            count -= 1
            i += 1 
            j-= 1

        return maX
            
fruits = input()
fruits = [int(i) for i in fruits.split()]
obj = Solution()
print(obj.totalFruit(fruits))
```

when I debug:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkHDE.png)

Comment: This condition is not restricted (checked) within the inner loop `while count_type < 3:` that increments j.

Comment: thank you very much, I fixed it. But I still don't understand why it has to be restricted one more time within the inner loop. Can you please explain for me?

Comment: Explanation: the condition was checked on the outer loop, but not in the inner loop where j also changes.  Meaning you check the condition before each iteration of the outer loop.  But, within the outer loop, the inner loop changes j to violate the condition which causes so index error.

Comment: thank you for your help. I didn't notice that I also change j in the inner loop.